# Angular router: match parent routes from child route

Tags: angular, routes

I have a url schema that defines a "context" from the url schema.
For this reason, I have the following "root" route:

```
{
 path: ':entitytype/:entityid/:viewtype',
 resolve: {
   context: (activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) =>
            inject(RouteDataProviderService).resolveParams(activatedRoute, state),
 },
 runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
 children: [ ... ],
}
```

The idea is, that the resolver builds the context (possibly performs an api call, etc.) and makes this available to all child routes as `data` property on the activated route.

Depending on `viewtype`, I want to load different child routes. But it seems that I cannot define a child route that "matches" the `viewType` of the parent.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
children: [
  {
     path: '../details', // does not work
     loadComponent: () => // DetailsComponent
   },
   {
      path: 'details', // does not work, obviously (results in `type/id/view/details`)
      loadComponent: () => ....
   },
],
```

To be clear, in the above example, `DetailsComponent` should be rendered if the url is something like `someEntityType/123/details`.

But it seems it's simply not possible to match a parent param from a child route.
Is there a workaround for this?